# Issue when using string operation and pipe together

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have a HTML in a Angular 2.0 template like following:

```
<span> Total Employee {{employeeCount> 0 ? '(' + employeeCount+ ')' : ''}} ></span>
```

My customFormatter takes a value and format it with coma separator if its a number.

It works fine. Now I want to use a custom pipe to format the employee count and I have used the following code:

```
<span> 
   Total Employee {{employeeCount> 0 ? '(' + employeeCount | customFormatter + ')' : ''}} >
</span>
```

But it gives syntax error: "Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Conditional expression..."

The pipe is working when I use as following:

```
<span> Total Employee {{employeeCount | customFormatter }} ></span>
```

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: check dupe just use `()`

Comment: thanks. its working when i have used it under parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You should be writing this logic inside your `customFormatter` pipe

```
export class CustomFormatterPipe implements PipeTransform{

     transform(employeeCount){
      if({employeeCount> 0){
          // your logic here
      } else {
           return '';
      }

}
```

Comment: Issue is not in pipe. its an issue for using pipe and string operation together

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a plunker

Comment: okay, trying and will update the question

Comment: waiting.... for it

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<span> 
Total Employee {{employeeCount> 0 ? '(' + employeeCount + ')'| customFormatter : ''}}
</span>
```

Comment: This will not help me. cause I want to concatenate after format and my custom for-matter format the number type value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to your problem, but one option would be to just make the entire `<span>` and its contents render only when there is a greater than zero employee count:

```
<span>
    Total Employee
    <span ng-show="employeeCount > 0">{{employeeCount | customFormatter}}</span>
</span>
```

When the count is zero then the span would not be visible, but would still take up the same space in the DOM, which presumably would be equivalent to rendering that span with just an empty string as content.

Comment: But when the value will be shown it should show within parenthesis after applying custom formatter

Comment: @Syedur Then just nest the span.